# Trying to create an empty grid

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class WorldMap (object):
def __init__ (self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    world = []
    for i in range(self.width):
        world.append(None)
        for j in range(self.height): 
                                world[i].append(None)


class WorldMap(object):
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.map = [[None for x in range(self.width)] for y in range(self.height)]
```

1. The second successfully creates a grid. I don't understand why the first code doesn't work.
2. to create an empty grid with lists, I tried using `None` and `''` in the first code, but neither work. Why are both `''` and `None` as used in the first code not correct ?

Comment: `numpy.zeros(width*height).reshape((width,height))` is your best, fastest, and simplest way of doing it ... at least imho ... plus familiarizing yourself with numpy arrays early on will help you tons later

Answer (score 3):

In your first code, the outer `i` loop:

```
world = []
for i in range(self.width):
    world.append(None)
```

creates a list of `None`:

```
world == [None, None, None, ...]
```

therefore in the inner `j` loop, when you call

```
world[i].append(None)
```

you are trying to call:

```
None.append(None)
```

and you can't append to `None`! The outer loop should have been:

```
world.append([]) # an empty list
```

Then the inner loop will work correctly with whatever (`None`, `""`, etc.) you want to put in those lists.

It is worth noting that the second version is much neater than the first, with (obviously!) less potential for error. However, a small improvement (as you never use `x` or `y`):

```
self.map = [[None for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code in the first loop you should be appending an empty list rather than `None`.
Also the second version is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the grid size will be:

`size = 4`

Now, we're making an empty grid:

`grid = []`

`for y in range(size):
   grid = grid + [[]]
   for x in range(size):
      grid[y] = grid[y] + [0]`

When you now call your `grid` you should get:
`[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

grid = [[0] * 20] * 20

Comment: This will create 20 copies of the same list, such that changing grid[0] will also change grid[1], grid[2], etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205.